# SQL Join Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My database table looks like this:

```
ID  Value
-------------
1   a1¦aa¦a2
1   b1¦aa¦b2
1   b3¦tt¦b3
2   a2¦aa¦z1
2   b2¦tt¦z2
2   b3¦tt¦z3
```

I'm trying to split each value up with ¦ as the break point which works:

```
Select 
    SUBSTRING(MT.Value, 1, CHARINDEX ( '¦' ,MT.Value) - 1) [part1],
    SUBSTRING(MT.Value, CHARINDEX ( '¦' ,MT.Value) + 1, 2) [part2],
    RIGHT(MT.Value,CHARINDEX('¦',REVERSE(MT.Value),0)-1) [part3]
from 
    mytable MT
where 
    MT.id = 1
```

But then I try to include a join to match up the records with id2 to id1 where the third part matches, SQL Server throws an error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Code:

```
Select 
    SUBSTRING(MT.Value, 1, CHARINDEX ( '¦' ,MT.Value) - 1) [part1],
    SUBSTRING(MT.Value, CHARINDEX ( '¦' ,MT.Value) + 1, 2) [part2],
    RIGHT(MT.Value, CHARINDEX('¦', REVERSE(MT.Value), 0) - 1) [part3],  
    mt1.value
Join 
    mytable mt1 on mt1.ID = 2
                and RIGHT(mt.Value, CHARINDEX('¦', REVERSE(mt.Value), 0) - 1) = SUBSTRING(mt1.Value, 1, CHARINDEX ( '¦' , mt1.Value) - 1)
where 
    MT.id = 1
from 
    mytable MT
```

Has anyone got any idea how else I can do it or where I'm going wrong?

Comment: missing the join link between tables?

Comment: Perhaps its just me, but I'm not clear on the desired output

Comment: Ideally you should avoid holding multiple values in one column.  If possible revisit your db design.  Each cell in the database should hold one scalar value.  You'll find it so much easier to read, validate and interact your with data.

Comment: @destination-data I completly agree but Im not in a position to make that change, its not my design.

Comment: @john cappelletti desired output is a table showing me where the last part of id1 = the first part of id2 but at the same time I need to split it into columns every time there's a broken pipe

Comment: Why don't you **study the [OFFICIAL MSDN documentation on `SELECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)** to see what the syntax should be like??? It should be `SELECT ... FROM ..... JOIN ... WHERE.....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a CHARINDEX for '¦' on the "Value" column then subtracting 1.  This mostly likely means there is at least 1 record in which the '¦' does not exist in the string.  So your CHARINDEX would = zero (0) then you subtract 1 is a negative number.  You cannot use a negative number in a substring or left function.

One solution is casing your statement:

```
[Part1] = 
    CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX ( '¦' ,MT.Value) = 0 THEN MT.Value
        ELSE SUBSTRING(MT.Value, 1, CHARINDEX ( '¦' ,MT.Value)-1)
    END
```

Comment: You were correct, some of the values didn't have ¦ because i forgot to put in the full criteria on the join, thanks for pointing out the obvious!

Answer (score 0):

As you have a working select statement why not wrap that in a [common table expression (CTE)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms175972.aspx).  Now you can reuse your returned columns.

To make it easier for everyone to share your sample data I've moved it into variable.

```
    DECLARE @Sample TABLE
    (
        ID      INT,
        [Value] VARCHAR(8)
    )
;


INSERT INTO @Sample
    (
        ID,
        [Value]
    )
VALUES
    (1,'a1¦aa¦a2'),
    (1,'b1¦aa¦b2'),
    (1,'b3¦tt¦b3'),
    (2,'a2¦aa¦z1'),
    (2,'b2¦tt¦z2'),
    (2,'b3¦tt¦z3')
;
```

I'm not entire sure I understood the requirement.  So I better explain what I have done.  This query returns all `ID` 1s that share a `Part1` with an `ID` 2.

```
WITH CTE AS 
    (
        /* Amended OP original query.
         * WHERE clause dropped and 
         * table name replaced with var.
         */
        SELECT
            Id,
            SUBSTRING(MT.Value, 1, CHARINDEX ( '¦' ,MT.Value)-1)    AS [part1],
            SUBSTRING(MT.Value, CHARINDEX ( '¦' ,MT.Value)+1, 2)    AS [part2],
            RIGHT(MT.Value,CHARINDEX('¦',REVERSE(MT.Value),0)-1)    AS [part3]
        FROM
            @Sample MT
    )
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE AS cte1
        INNER JOIN CTE AS cte2      ON cte2.part1 = cte1.part1
WHERE
    cte1.ID = 1
    AND cte2.ID = 2
;
```